# Animation callbacks for ImageSwitcher Android

Tags: android, animation, callback, imageswitcher

I am using an ImageSwitcher to display a series of images with animations for transitions.
Is there a way I can pace the transition based on the duration of the animation?
Is it possible to have an AnimationListener or something of that sort to identify the start and end of an animation?

Comment: regarding animation listener: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html

Comment: define a custom IN and OUT animations with a specific duration set in your animation xmls